# Number decimal is displaying wrong

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am defining my numberfield and then I amgetting some value like this

`val = 3.555678`

I am using `decimalPrecision : 3` in my number field so The value is displaying is **3.556**

I want my value should be display **3.555** so for that I am using

`val = val.toFixed(3);`

val is coming in consol 3.555
then `numberfield.setValue(val);`
But in UI it is still comming 3.556

Why it is coming this.

Comment: how can 4.555678 toFixed(3) become 3.555? or 3.556 ... typo?

Comment: ignoring the typo  ... `var val=3.555678; val = val.toFixed(3); console.log(val);` outputs the string `"3.556"` every time

Comment: how is it possible that 4.555678 become 3.555 after using toFixed?

Comment: bistromathics, @jitendravarshney

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes.. So Is there way by which I can so exact value 3.555

Comment: yes, understanding how rounding works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to display **3.555** you can do it in the following way

```js
let val = 3.555678

let decimalPrecision = 3;

let roundedval = val.toFixed(3);

if(roundedval > val){
  val = roundedval - Math.pow(10, -1*decimalPrecision);
}

console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var val=3.555678; 
val = Math.floor (val*1000)/1000;
console.log(val);
```